# UIWebView doesnot load pages properly in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, epub

I am new to iPhone,

I made ePub reader app, in which i am loading local `.html` page in my `webview`.

when i load my `.html` page it works properly but after some time it does not load properly. something unexpected things gets loads in my webview like html page's text color gets changes,backgorung color gets changes and images gets resizes and all several unexpected things occurs, when this things occurs at a same time when i click on button and on click when i call `[webview reload]`  then everything again gets works fine.

**Why this is occuring ?**

I am creating webview in `viewDidLoad`

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:webView]; 
[webView release];
```

**Any help will be appriciated.**